# T-SQL datetime variable behaves differently than getdate()

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, execution-time

Needed to redo a query (lots of *inner joins* with about 20 tables) which used the current date (`getdate()`) for selecting the items.

The request was to allow the user to specify a certain date instead of `getdate()`.
Declared a variable `@mydate` as `datetime = getdate()` and replaced all the `getdate()` in the query with `@mydate`.

The query execution time jumped up from 10 s to 6 minutes! and the execution plan completely changed.

Spent quite some time investigating why this happend and finally a

```
option (optimize for (`@mydate = '2000-01-01'`))
```

did the trick - although it looks to me like something that shouldn't be necessary because my variable definition looked like

```
declare @mydate as datetime = getdate()
```

and should not give room for variant interpretation?

My question:

Is it a general recommendation in T-SQL to specify variable example values in all queries or is only `datetime` a (possible, it's not a general issue from my experience) problem?

Comment: In general, no values nor datatypes are a problem, including `datetime`.  This is something specific to your situation, which we cannot possibly determine because you have given us virtually no information.

Answer (score 2):

This really has nothing to do with the fact that the variable happened to be a datetime variable, it is an artifact of the query optimizer logic.

When you use a constant (or getdate()) the optimizer understands how it can use that expression when it determines the indexes etc. that can use to make an optimal query.

As you discovered, the option optimize for essentially restores the known "constant" version of query, so it will run fast again.

I have bumped against this issue quite a few times over the years, the solution is not always obvious -- i.e., you can't just automatically use the option optimize to fix it. It shows up in number of ways, as seen in [this article](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/11/t-sql-queries/ten-common-threats-to-execution-plan-quality) on problematic execution plans.

ADDED

I did some more searching and found [Constant Folding and Expression Evaluation During Cardinality Estimation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175933(v=sql.105).aspx) specifically related to your specific problem.

Comment: Added article on constant folding